# C# System.FormatException: "Входная строка имела неверный формат."

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

[image: Вся проблема]

Здравствуйте, возникла ошибка во время отладки. В самом коде ошибок не было.

```
using System;


namespace Гипер_инстремент
{ 
   class Program {

    class Anekdots {

            string a1;
            string a2;
            string a3;

            public void Anekdot()
    {
                a1 = "Новый год — это повод встретиться со всеми родственниками и вспомнить, почему конкретно вы живёте отдельно.";
                a2 = "Свой первый срок по малолетке я отбывал в углу.";
                a3 = "В 2 часа ночи во мне просыпается философ, в 3 часа – мечтатель, а в 7 часов – невыспавшийся человек.";
        int x1 = Convert.ToInt32(a1);
        int x2 = Convert.ToInt32(a2);
        int x3 = Convert.ToInt32(a3);
        Random rnd1 = new Random();
        int rn1 = rnd1.Next(x1, x3);
        Console.WriteLine(rn1);
    }

}


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Что вы хотите ?");
            Console.WriteLine("Писать только цифрами");
            Console.WriteLine("1.Анекдот");
            Console.WriteLine("2.Калькулятор");
            Console.WriteLine("3.Загадки");
            int nym1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            switch(nym1)
        {
                case 1:
            Anekdots p1 = new Anekdots();
                    p1.Anekdot();
                    break;
        }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: код лучше вставлять как текст, а не картинку

Comment: Так посмотрите что у вас в коде вы строку(string) хотите перевести в цифры(int)

Comment: А как тогда сделать лучше, OXYGEN? 
Я просто новенький  в C#

Comment: `Здравствуйте, возникла ошибка во время отладки. В самом коде ошибок не было.` в сомом коде хватает ошибок, у вас тоже самое с х1 х2 х3

Comment: String не совместим с Int в данном случае. 
Ошибка возникла во время отладки, потому что это ошибка компиляции, так как для компилятора нормально, что вы пытаетесь преобразовать string в int, но в вашем случае он не может сопоставить буквам цифры, поэтому и выдает значение.
Судя по вашему коду, вам нужно добавить параметр в метод Anekdots, и в зависимости от цифры 1-3, выводить на консоль один из анекдотов.

Comment: если я правильно понял, то вам надо проверять результат конвертации: можно или нет конвертировать строку в число. Почитайте в [этой теме](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1019793/5752652) про TryParse

Comment: на сколько я понимаю вы хотите вывести один из анекдотов случайным образом для этого рекомендую switch

Comment: Пожалуйста, OXYGEN, дайте пример.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот быстрый пример:

```
  class Anekdots
    {
        List<string> _anekdotlist = new List<string>();

        public void Anekdot()
        {
            _anekdotlist.Add("Новый год — это повод встретиться со всеми родственниками и вспомнить, почему конкретно вы живёте отдельно");
            _anekdotlist.Add("Свой первый срок по малолетке я отбывал в углу.");
            _anekdotlist.Add("В 2 часа ночи во мне просыпается философ, в 3 часа – мечтатель, а в 7 часов – невыспавшийся человек.");
            Random rnd1 = new Random();

            int rn1 = rnd1.Next(0, _anekdotlist.Count - 1);
            Console.WriteLine(_anekdotlist[rn1]);
        }


    }
```